# IS THIS BIKE SAFE

Tags: frames

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/S1PKL2uMXwJc2aGjGEybc8ZM4CFk-i5EHWrkZxLSVaD29xUrfIig1ap1dp6Na-WsjMc-Tw=s85

[image]

I M LOOKING TO BUY THIS BIKE AND I WOUD LIKE TO KNOW IF IT IS SAFE TO RIDE

Comment: Given the size of the photo, I can't even tell whether it's a bike, let alone whether it's safe to ride.

Comment: @Diado I can't even tell whether it's a photo! Seriously, though, NEJC, you need to provide a clear, high-resolution photograph. Even then, it would probably be very hard for anyone to say "yes" because only you can be responsible for your safety. Trust your gut: if you think the bike _might not_ be safe, don't buy it.

Comment: Also, please don't write in all caps. It's hard to read and it's usually interpreted as "shouting".

Comment: You guys are more brave than I (or perhaps browse in a better sandbox than I do) for clicking that link...

Comment: Can't tell if the image is a stationary exercise bike or some kind of lawncare tool like a mower.  Google image search recognises a "Road Bike" though which is impressive.

Answer (score 2):

We can't tell you.   However you can do a basic M check to test for the common failures.

https://www.sustrans.org.uk/what-you-can-do/cycling/your-bike/bicycle-maintenance-made-easy/m-check-your-bike-11-steps documents how to check over a bike.

You start at the front, and work up from the wheel/axle to the bars, then down to the BB, up to the saddle, and down to the rear hub.  This encourages thoroughness.

**If anything looks or feels wrong then it probably is wrong** so first search this site for more relevant questions, or ask a fresh specific question if we've not covered it already.