# Do Silverfox have a website?

Tags: mountain-bike

I about 12-13 years ago I bought a Silverfox Slither mountain bike on a whim, and after the initial excitement wore off, I have rarely used it over the years.  Fast forward to today, I've got back into riding and I'd like to see if I can obtain a manual for the bike so that I can look at the maintenance advice etc.  I cannot for the life of me find a website for Silverfox and apart from the odd second-hand sales websites, there's not a lot of mention of the bike online.

How can I find a copy of said manual?

thanks

Comment: If google can't find one, you're probably not going to find one.  Can you tell us what you're trying to accomplish - a general maintenance process, or is there something specific you want to fix?   A fork suspension service could be important, even if its still working fine.

Comment: Meh, I mean, is Silverfox even a real company?  There's plenty of bikes by them but nothing about the company anywhere?  I'm just looking at general maintenance of the bike, I wanted the manual for specifics to do with the gears, suspension, brakes etc.

Comment: There are only a handful of bike component manufacturers and even between them the components are usually similar, so generic instructions are just fine. To me it looks like Silverfox is just a name used for marketing cheap Chinese bikes.

Comment: @Biggus69 Start with a basic M check as per this answer https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/58376/19705   If anything seems not right on your bike, search for existing questions here, and if nothing then ask a new question.  [chat] may also be an option.

Comment: You can identify most components just from looking at them, reading the labels, measuring etc.  If you are unsure, you can also post a photo of a component and ask.