# What kind of bicycle do I have? manufacturer/model..frame?

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, identify-this-bike

I'm trying to figure out what kind of bicycle I have.  I'm pretty new to this.

When I started taking a closer look at my bike I realized that there are two different stickers on the frame.  One says `Outback mountain bike` and the other says `Overland 6000`.   They are both on the frame.  It's a nice bike but I would like to know what kind of bike I have.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

https://photos.app.goo.gl/Z45eYiAx6usXQxYA8

Comment: Please take the bike out of the vehicle and take some clear pictures. [How do I ask a good "ID My Bike" question](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question) I'm pretty sure this is a very nice bike that can be identified but we need better pictures.

Comment: Please take some nice picture, the best one you can take is one in clear light with the bicycle upside down, so we can see the code stamped on the frame, right below and in between the pedals

Answer (score 8):

A quick google search reveals.... nothing much of interest.   I suspect you have a big-box-store BSO which is physically identical to many other bikes, but perhaps with different stickers.  There's nothing wrong with that, as long as the bike gets used.

Unfortunately Overlander and Outback are two models of a vehicle, which seems to clutter search results.

---

The head tube badge seems to say OB or DB, but I don't recognise it.

The bike's frame would be called a "rigid MTB" and probably dates from the 90s.  The typefaces in the logos also suggest that.

The bike's fork is rotated 180 degrees at the moment, probably partialy because its wedged in the backseat of a car.  Get it out, air up the tyres, give it a quick M check for safety, and give it a ride.

Some light lubrication may be required if its been sitting for a while, but that bike looks eminently rideable.

Comment: What's a M check?

Comment: @EricDuminil that would be a good question to ask on the main page - we don't appear to have that as a question/answer yet.  In short, its a formalised quick once-over of a bike, checking all the main points.    https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/58376/19705